# SCSS min() with both px and percentage units

Tags: sass

I am writing a small rails app, where I have a requirement to use the min() function like this:

```css
img {
    width: min(75%, 250px);
}
```

In firefox, from CSS inspector, I can just set it, and it works. But in SCSS, I get a compilation error:

```
Internal Error: Incompatible units: 'px' and '%'.
```

If I use hard-coded px units like `min(250px, 350px)`, it works, but it makes no sense to use `min()` at all, I can just use `250px` instead, and that's not what I want.

Is that possible to use `min()` with both `px` and `%` units?

Comment: Using `Dart SASS` here in `VS Code` it compiles to correct CSS `img { width: min(75%, 250px); }`. What SASS compiler and/or SASS version do you use? Maybe can someone check? (Notice: most actual Sass version is 'Dart Sass')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that both CSS and SCSS has the same `min()` function, and there was a conflict. But SCSS is actually case sensitive, while CSS isn't so I was able to write `Min()` or `MIN()` instead. That worked just fine. I don't think this is something more than a hack though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `calc()` because this will make the browser calculate how many pixels the percentage is.

```
img {
  width: min(calc(75%), 250px);
}
```